# gh-pages files availibility

Tags: github, github-pages

Usually a file `github.com/user/repo/blob/gh-pages/index.html` is available in `user.github.io/repo/index.html`.

In the same way `github.com/user/repo/blob/gh-pages/style.css` is served at `user.github.io/repo/style.css`.

Recently I had this issue: **my file `md/_hello.md` in gh-pages isn't served at `user.github.io/repo/md/_hello.md`. Why?**

---

Real life example: https://github.com/josephernest/0Doc-chip/blob/gh-pages/md/_welcome-to-derp.md isn't served here https://josephernest.github.io/0Doc-chip/md/_welcome-to-derp.md (Page not found). Why?

Comment: Is it always true in github pages that files that start with an underscore are missing or alway when using Jekyll? This article seems only about Jekyll: 
https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/

Answer (score 3):

To solve this, you must add a `.nojekyll`

Create the file in the root of your repository, and give it a minute to update. Should now work as expected.